# method not found laravel model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

i have 2 model, JadwalTerapisKlinik and PesertaKlinik.

i try to call data using this code :

```
$data = JadwalTerapisKlinik::whereHas('pesertaKlinik', function($q){
                $q->whereHas('timeControlling', function($qq){
                    $qq->where('status', 'done');
                });
            })->with(['pesertaKlinik' => function($q){
                $q->with(['timeControlling' => function($qq){
                    $qq->where('status', 'done');
                }]);
            }])->orderBy('tanggal', 'desc')->get();
    $data = $data->pesertaKlinik()->paginate(10);
```

but the result is "Method pesertaKlinik does not exist."

this is method pesertaKlinik in JadwalTerapisKlinik model :

```
public function pesertaKlinik(){
    return $this->hasMany(PesertaKlinik::class, 'jadwal_terapis_id');
}
```

but when i use `find(1)` on first query not `get()` , its working fine.

structure model : JadwalTerapis has many PesertaKlinik, PesertaKlinik has one TimeControlling.

whats wrong with my code ? thank you in advance.

Comment: Please add the structure of your models `JadwalTerapisKlinik`, `pesertaKlinik`, and `timeControlling`.

Comment: structure model : JadwalTerapis has many PesertaKlinik, PesertaKlinik has one TimeControlling.

Comment: Is the `tanggal` column part of `JadwalTerapisKlinik`'s schema?

Comment: check if my answer can help.

Answer (score 1):

You should use only `get() => to execute your query` or `paginate() => to execute the query and paginate the results`. Not both chained.

You can always use the command `toSql()` instead `get()` to check whether your query is written the way it should be.

Comment: i was deleted `get()` and still get error result `Call to undefined method`

Answer (score 0):

The `get` call on the builder is returning you a collection of models not a single model instance. Collections do not have a `pesertaKlinik` method.

Perhaps you are looking for the `first` method on the builder to return a single model instance or null instead of the `get` method.

Comment: actually i want get all timecontrolling and pesertaKlinik data with order by  `tanggal` column in `JadwalTerapis`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call the `paginate()` function on a collection that is already retrieved via `get()`. Meanwile, I think you can query your `JadwalTerapisKlinik` model in a briefer approach by *nesting* relationships with `.` as in the following:

```
$data = JadwalTerapisKlinik::whereHas('pesertaKlinik.timeControlling', function($q){
            $q->where('status', 'done');
        })->orderBy('tanggal', 'desc')->paginate(10);  // instead of get(), call your paginate() method here
```

Now similarly, your ***eager loaded relationships*** with the above query would look like the following:

```
$data = JadwalTerapisKlinik::whereHas('pesertaKlinik.timeControlling', function($q){
            $q->where('status', 'done');
        })->with(['pesertaKlinik.timeControlling' => function($q){
            $q->where('status', 'done');
        }])->orderBy('tanggal', 'desc')->paginate(10);
```

The `$data` variable now contains a *collection* of `JadwalTerapisKlinik` models with the specified constraints via `whereHas`, and the eager loaded relationships with `with`.

Therefore, to be able to iterate over the collections and their data, you'll definitely need a loop (in your controller code, or in your view):

```
foreach($data as $singleInstance){
    $prestaKliniks = $singleInstance->prestaKlinik; // same as $singleInstance->prestaKlinic()->get();
    $timeControlling = $singleInstance->prestaKlinik->timeControlling;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, what i want is call all data `pesertaKlinik` with orderBy column `tanggal` in `JadwalTerapisKlinik`. i need a simple code, but i cant found it. so i use this `PesertaKlinik::join('jadwal_terapis',  'peserta_klinik.jadwal_terapis_id', '=', 'jadwal_terapis.id')
                ->orderBy('jadwal_terapis.tanggal', 'desc')
                ->paginate(15);`
thank you for trying to help me :)

Comment: You're welcome, but always be free to check out the power you can get with Eloquent.